# Como alimentar SELECT com Webservice SOAP em PHP?

Tags: php, web-service, soap, soapclient

Tenho de listar um em um SELECT (html) produtos de uma empresa utilizando um webservice. Algum código exemplo ?

**Código Cliente:**

```
<?php
    //cliente

    //inclusao do arquivo NUSOAP
    require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

    //criacao de uma instancia do cliente
    $client = new nusoap_client('http://127.0.0.1/webservicephp/server2.php');

    //chamada do metodo SOAP
    $result = $client->call('listaProdutos');


    //exibe o resultado
    print_r($result);
```

**Código do Server:**

```
<?php
    //server
    //inclusao do arquivo NUSOAP
    require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

    //criacao de uma instanca do servidor
    $server = new soap_server;

    //registro do método
    $server->register('listaProdutos');


    function listaProdutos(){

        $produtos = "produto1"."produto2";      
        return $result;
    }


    //requisição para uso do serviço
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ?
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';

    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver desta forma:

**Código server**

```
<?php
    //server
    //inclusao do arquivo NUSOAP
    require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

    //criacao de uma instanca do servidor
    $server = new soap_server;

    //registro do método
    $server->register('listaProdutos');


    function listaProdutos(){

        $produtos = array("volvo","saab","mercedes","audi","fiat","bmw");       
        return $produtos;
    }


    //requisição para uso do serviço
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ?
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';

    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

?>
```

**Código cliente**

```
<?php
    //cliente

    //inclusao do arquivo NUSOAP
    require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

    //criacao de uma instancia do cliente
    $client = new nusoap_client('http://127.0.0.1/webservicephp/server2.php');

    //chamada do metodo SOAP
    $result = $client->call('listaProdutos');


?>

<select>
  <?php

        //exibe o resultado
        $top = sizeof($result) - 1;
        $bottom = 0;
        while($bottom <= $top)
        {
            echo '<option value='.$result[$bottom].'>'.$result[$bottom].'</option>';
            $bottom++;
        }
  ?>

</select>
```

[image: webserviceSOAP]